# JPA handling of Query-parameter Limitation of SQLServer

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa

SQLServer has a hard limit of 2100 parameters within a query. Sometime we have to deal with statements doing an update on an unknown number of elements, like

```
query.where(root.get(Entity_.id).in(list));
```

If it cannot be guaranteed, that list is restricted in size, we always have to put some boilerplate code around the statement itself, splitting the list in chunks and calling the statement on these chunks. This works, but is ugly.

Is there some built in mechanism in JPA to automatically split on SQLServer?

Comment: What Jpa implementation are you using, Hibernate?

Comment: Are you using Hibernate or EclipseLink?

Comment: We are using hibernate but currently do not employ implementation-specific details. If possible, we would like to keep it that way.